# MySQL works fine with GUI, but won't start without it. Ubuntu-mate

Tags: networking, server, mysql, raspberrypi, ubuntu-mate

This one is making me nuts. I have a Raspberry PI 2B with a Ubuntu-mate 16.04 installation. I use it to run PLexmediaserver and Owncloud, the last one over Apache, MySQL and PHP 7.0.

Ubuntu-mate for Raspberry PI comes with a simple script to switch between GUI and Bash: graphical disable/enable, then; reboot.

Whenever I boot up with GUI - that's: after sudo-ing graphical enable - MySQL starts flawlessly.

I would very much like, on the other hand, to run the system without GUI, in order to save some RAM. The problem is that whenever I reboot after sudo-ing graphical disable, MySQL service won't start.

`systemctl status mysql.service` returns the following:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
   Active: inactive (dead) (Result: exit-code) since Qui 2016-06-09 13:06:48 BRT
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, sc
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too qui
Jun 09 13:06:48 raspPI systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

For now I'll keep running the GUI. Any ideas?